# Ceph encodes query string in object name

Tags: kubernetes, ceph

We're running Ceph Object Gateway S3 in k8s. Current problem manifests when object name has query string appended to its name. For example, take the following key that's supposed to be saved in Ceph using S3 API:

```
/path/to/file.jpg?foo=bar
```

It's not possible to retrieve the file using a publicly-facing URL, such as:

```
https://ceph.domain.com/bucket-name/path/to/file.jpg?foo=bar
```

But it does work with:

```
https://ceph.domain.com/bucket-name/path/to/file.jpg%3Ffoo%3Dbar
                                                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Did anyone also had that problem? If so, how to circumvent that? Theoretically, we could rewrite each URL on ingress controller to change `%3F` to `?` and `%3D` to `=` but frankly that sounds not so smart. Also, AWS S3 does not have any problem with special characters.